# The bootstrap navbar covers the whole page,but not all the pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm building a website for a restaurant.The navigation bar is covering the whole page,but just on specific pages(cart,login,register).On home page or menu page it works normally.
I was working on home page and after that, when i tried to go on login, the navigation bar was on the whole page.I don't know why it's doing this and more bizzar is that it's doing it on specific pages.
In home html i added comments tag for you to know what i had added before the problem appeared.

Image: [image: Image for demonstration]

HTML from Home page:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/home-style.css"/>
</head>
<div class="container min-h main-container">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/pizza.jpg" alt="" style="height: 450px;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h1>Cea mai buna mancare din oras</h1>
                        <h3>Preturi mici</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/poza2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 450px;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h1>Cea mai buna mancare din oras</h1>
                        <h3>Preturi mici</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/poza1.jpg" alt="" style="height: 450px;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h1>Cea mai buna mancare din oras</h1>
                        <h3>Preturi mici</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        **<!--This is what i added before the problem-->
        <section class="title-bestsellers">
            <h1 class="text-center">Cele mai vandute produse</h1>
        </section>
        <div class="food-container">
            <div class="product-container">
                <h3 class="text-center">Mancare Calda</h3>
                <hr>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/pizza.jpg" class="product-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
                <h3 class="text-center">Carne de porc</h3>
                <hr>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/pizza.jpg" class="product-image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
                <h3 class="text-center">Garnituri</h3>
                <hr>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/pizza.jpg" class="product-image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two-wrappers">
            <div class="inner-static-img" id="left-inner-img">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('meniu');?>" class="img-link"><h2>Meniu</h2></a>
                <a href="pizza.php" class="img-link"><h4>Arunca o privite in meniu.Sigur o sa-ti placa!</h4></a>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-static-img" id="right-inner-img">
                <h2>Noutati</h2>
                <h4>Incearca ulimele aparaitii in meniu!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Untill here-->**
</div>
```

CSS for home page:

```
    .title-bestsellers{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
}
h4{
    color: white;
}
.carousel{
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.main-container{
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.two-wrappers{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.inner-static-img{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis: 49%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color:white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.inner-static-img h2,h4{
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
}
.carousel{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.carousel-caption{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;
}
#left-inner-img{
    background: url(../images/left.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#right-inner-img{
    background-image: url(../images/right.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
a.img-link{
     text-decoration: none;
}
.img-link h2:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.img-link h4:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

/*cele mai vandute*/
.food-container{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.product-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    flex-basis: 30%;
}
.product-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.product-container p{
    text-align: center;
}
/*sfarsit cele mai vandute*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .two-wrappers{
        display: block;
    }
    .inner-static-img{
        margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
}
@media(min-width: 900px) {
    .food-container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .body{
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 900px){
    .food-container{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Header:

```
    <?php $categories = $this->products_model->get_all_categories();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>English Park Canteen</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/header-style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url('acasa');?>">English Park Canteen</a>
    <div class="d-flex order-lg-1 ml-auto pr-2">
        <?php if($this->cart->total()> 0):?>
            <span class="dot" style="color:white; padding-right: 5px;">( <?php echo $this->cart->total();?> lei )</span>
        <?php endif;?>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('cos'); ?>" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row to-hide-nav">
            <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
            <li class="nav-item mx-2 mx-lg-0">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('login');?>">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('register');?>">Register</a>
            </li>
            <?php else:?>
            <li class="nav-item mx-2 mx-lg-0">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('name');?></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
            <?php endif;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler mt-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('acasa');?>">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Meniu
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo site_url('/menu/'.$category['category_name']);?>"><?php echo $category['category_name'];?></a>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a href="tel:0746-117-702"><p class="dropdown-item">0746117702</p></a>
                    <a href="tel:0742112452"><p class="dropdown-item">0742112452</p></a>
                    <a href="tel:0735212352"><p class="dropdown-item">0735212352</p></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
                <li class="nav-item to-hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('login');?>">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item to-hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('register');?>">Register</a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
                <li class="nav-item to-hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('profil');?>"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('name');?></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item to-hide">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('user_loggedin')): ?>
    <div class="hide-it text-center"><?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_loggedin').'</p>'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('user_loggedout')): ?>
    <div class="hide-it text-center"><?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_loggedout').'</p>'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('check_email_exists')): ?>
    <div class="hide-it text-center"><?php echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->session->flashdata('check_email_exists').'</p>'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('user_registered')): ?>
    <div class="hide-it text-center"><?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_registered').'</p>'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('order_placed')): ?>
    <div class="hide-it text-center"><?php echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('order_placed').'</p>'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".hide-it").fadeOut(3000);
    });
</script>
```

CSS for Header:

```
.bg-dark{
    background-color: #000!important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    background-color: black;
}
.dropdown-item{
    color: white!important;
}
.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover{
    background-color: #333333;
}
.alert{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1370px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.test{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .to-hide{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .to-hide-nav{
        display: none;
    }
    .container{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) {
    .to-hide{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .to-hide-nav{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

One page that have the problem:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/css/lr-style.css"/>
</head>

<?php echo form_open('users/login'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="to-be-center">
        <div class="title-center">
            <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $title;?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="name-input form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="password-input form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Parola"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-black" value="Login" name="login"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
}
.to-be-center{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn-black{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.alert{
    margin-top: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
    .btn-black{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Any ideea why?...I know it's a lot of code...sorry!

Comment: Issue is due to the container class inside the header which also gets 100% width and height , try changing that container class to container-fluid inside header.html

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">   change to <nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid"> in Header.html

Comment: thanks @Mitca, if my answer helped to solve your issue, you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, change the **container** class inside Header.html to  **container-fluid**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
```

change to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
```

code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WzYwyo

Issue is due to the container class inside the header which also gets 100% width and height , try changing that container class to container-fluid inside header.html